# Passing a pointer as a template parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I encounter a weird issue. In both C++03 and C++11, the following code is fine:

```
int someArray[] = {1,2,3,4};

template<int* ptr>
void function() {
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  function<someArray>();
  return 0;
}
```

But if you put `someArray` in main, it no longer works in C++03 and C++11. Why is this? Also why does `someArray` need to be `constexpr` in main but not outside of main? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is weird: "X worked in C++03. Now Y doesn't work in C++11". One question at a time? Or in other words, what does C++03 vs C++11 have to do with the question?

Comment: Because I try in both.

Comment: OK, but it still doesn't matter, so it's just cluttering up the question. You could say the same about *any* question, or you could add tons of other detail ("I tried this on Mondays, Wednesdays and when wearing a bikini"), but that doesn't mean that the detail is relevant, unless you have explicit reason to believe that it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Template arguments have to be constant expressions. The address of an object that is a variable with external linkage is a constant expression; the address of a function-local object is not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that definition of the language requires the array (object) that is used as a parameter  of the template, to be static. Static objects have names that are know at the compile time. This name is embedded into the name of the template instantiation. This is the way how templates in C++ work.

Each instantiation of the template has its own machine code for all functions, classes, enums, etc, These classes, functions, etc. have their own names in each instantiation. These names are based on parameters. Parameter can be either a value, or reference/pointer to static const object or a template. In all three cases it should have global scope. Definition of the language requires this.

You may argue that with an additional effort compiler could understand what you are asking for. Well, it could, but the language spec does nor ask the compiler writers to do this effort.

Answer (score 0):

Template parameters have to be known at compile time. `someArray` is not know  at compile time.